# Why is PyOpenGL rendering shapes that have been removed?

Tags: python, pyopengl

I am making an implementation of the marching cubes algorithm using PyQt5 and PyOpenGL. I have finally got it to march, draw points, and draw a mesh using the following code. The only issue is that when it cycles back, the meshes from the previous cycle are drawn. Even if the filter has changed, the original meshes are drawn.

What am I doing wrong?

cubes.py:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
                             QApplication, QMainWindow, QSlider,
                             QOpenGLWidget, QLabel, QPushButton
                            )
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from OpenGL.GL import (
                       glLoadIdentity, glTranslatef, glRotatef,
                       glClear, glBegin, glEnd,
                       glColor3fv, glVertex3fv,
                       GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT,
                       GL_QUADS, GL_LINES
                      )
from OpenGL.GLU import gluPerspective
from numerics import sin, cos, tan, avg, rnd
from classes import *
from lookup import table
import random, time

class mainWindow(QMainWindow):    #Main class.
    shapes = []    #place all instaces of shapes in this list in order to have them rendered.
    dataPoints = []
    zoomLevel = -10
    rotateDegreeV = -90
    rotateDegreeH = 0
    marchActive = False
    limit = -1
    meshPoints = []
    meshSectors = []

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):    #This is the keypress detector.
        try:
            key = event.key()
        except:
            key = -1    
        #print(key)
        if key == 87:
            self.rotateV(5)
        elif key == 65:
            self.rotateH(5)
        elif key == 83:
            self.rotateV(-5)
        elif key == 68:
            self.rotateH(-5)
        elif key == 67:
            self.zoom(1)
        elif key == 88:
            self.zoom(-1)
        elif key == 77:
            self.marchStep()

    def __init__(self):
        super(mainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.currentStep = 0
        self.width = 700    #Variables used for the setting of the size of everything
        self.height = 600
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, self.width + 50, self.height)    #Set the window size
        self.initData(3, 3, 3)

    def setupUI(self):
        self.openGLWidget = QOpenGLWidget(self)    #Create the GLWidget
        self.openGLWidget.setGeometry(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
        self.openGLWidget.initializeGL()
        self.openGLWidget.resizeGL(self.width, self.height)    #Resize GL's knowledge of the window to match the physical size?
        self.openGLWidget.paintGL = self.paintGL    #override the default function with my own?

        self.filterSlider = QSlider(Qt.Vertical, self)
        self.filterSlider.setGeometry(self.width + 10, int(self.height / 2) - 100, 30, 200)
        self.filterSlider.valueChanged[int].connect(self.filter)

        self.limitDisplay = QLabel(self)
        self.limitDisplay.setGeometry(self.width, int(self.height / 2) - 130, 50, 30)
        self.limitDisplay.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.limitDisplay.setText('-1')

        self.marchButton = QPushButton(self)
        self.marchButton.setGeometry(self.width, int(self.height / 2) - 160, 50, 30)
        self.marchButton.setText('March!')
        self.marchButton.clicked.connect(self.marchStep)

    def initData(self, sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ):
        marchSizeX = sizeX - 1
        marchSizeY = sizeY - 1
        marchSizeZ = sizeZ - 1
        xOff = -(sizeX / 2) + 0.5
        yOff = -(sizeY / 2) + 0.5
        zOff = -(sizeZ / 2) + 0.5
        xMarchOff = -(marchSizeX / 2) + 0.5
        yMarchOff = -(marchSizeY / 2) + 0.5
        zMarchOff = -(marchSizeZ / 2) + 0.5
        self.marchPoints = []
        for z in range(marchSizeZ):
            for y in range(marchSizeY):
                for x in range(marchSizeX):
                    self.marchPoints.append((x + xMarchOff, y + yMarchOff ,z + zMarchOff))

        for z in range(sizeZ):
            for y in range(sizeY):
                for x in range(sizeX):
                    val = self.generate(x + xOff, y + yOff, z + zOff)
                    dpColor = (0, (val + 1) / 2, (val + 1) / -2 + 1)
                    dpShape = cube((x + xOff, y + yOff, z + zOff), drawWires = False, drawFaces = True, color = dpColor)
                    dp = dataPoint((x + xOff, y + yOff, z + zOff), val, dpShape)
                    self.dataPoints.append(dp)
                    self.shapes.append(dpShape)

    def paintGL(self):
        #This function uses shape objects, such as cube() or meshSector(). Shape objects require the following:
        #a list named 'vertices' - This list is a list of points, from which edges and faces are drawn.
        #a list named 'wires'    - This list is a list of tuples which refer to vertices, dictating where to draw wires.
        #a list named 'facets'   - This list is a list of tuples which refer to vertices, ditating where to draw facets.
        #a bool named 'render'   - This bool is used to dictate whether or not to draw the shape.
        #a bool named 'drawWires' - This bool is used to dictate whether wires should be drawn.
        #a bool named 'drawFaces' - This bool is used to dictate whether facets should be drawn.

        glLoadIdentity()
        gluPerspective(45, self.width / self.height, 0.1, 110.0)    #set perspective?
        glTranslatef(0, 0, self.zoomLevel)    #I used -10 instead of -2 in the PyGame version.
        glRotatef(self.rotateDegreeV, 1, 0, 0)    #I used 2 instead of 1 in the PyGame version.
        glRotatef(self.rotateDegreeH, 0, 0, 1)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        if len(self.shapes) != 0:
            glBegin(GL_LINES)
            for s in self.shapes:
                glColor3fv(s.color)
                if s.render and s.drawWires:
                    for w in s.wires:
                        for v in w:
                            glVertex3fv(s.vertices[v])
            glEnd()

            glBegin(GL_QUADS)
            for s in self.shapes:
                glColor3fv(s.color)
                if s.render and s.drawFaces:
                    for f in s.facets:
                        for v in f:
                            glVertex3fv(s.vertices[v])
            glEnd()

    def marchStep(self):
        print(self.currentStep)
        if not self.marchActive:    #initialize
            marchAddr = len(self.shapes)
            self.marchingCube = cube(size = 1)
            self.shapes.append(self.marchingCube)
            self.marchActive = True
            self.currentStep = 0

        if self.currentStep == len(self.marchPoints):    #1 step after last
            self.marchingCube.hide()
            self.currentStep += 1
            for mp in self.meshPoints:
                mp.shape.hide()
            self.meshPoints = []
            self.openGLWidget.update()
            return
        if self.currentStep == len(self.marchPoints) + 1:    #2 steps after last
            #print('meshPoints: {}'.format(self.meshPoints))
            for mp in self.meshPoints:
                #print(mp.shape)
                self.shapes.remove(mp.shape)
            self.meshPoints.clear()
            for shape in self.shapes:
                if shape in self.meshSectors:
                    self.shapes.remove(shape)
            self.meshSectors = []
            self.currentStep = -1
            self.openGLWidget.update()
            return

        if self.currentStep == -1:    #1 step before first
            self.marchingCube.hide()
            self.currentStep += 1
            print('self.meshPoints: {}\nself.meshSectors: {}\nself.shapes: {}'.format(self.meshPoints, self.meshSectors, self.shapes))
            self.openGLWidget.update()
            return

        self.marchingCube.show()
        p = self.marchPoints[self.currentStep]
        x, y, z = p
        self.marchingCube.move((x, y, z))
        points = []
        for i in range(8):
            #print(self.marchingCube.vertices[i])
            point = self.getDataPointByLocation(self.marchingCube.vertices[i])
            points.append(point)

        #place meshpoints and highlight the active ones.
        MPs = []
        for pair in self.marchingCube.wires:
            pointA = points[pair[0]]
            pointB = points[pair[1]]
            #print('pointA.value: {}  pointB.value: {}  limit: {}'.formatpointA.value, pointB.value, self.limit)
            xA, yA, zA = pointA.location
            xB, yB, zB = pointB.location
            valA = (pointA.value + 1) / 2
            valB = (pointB.value + 1) / 2
            xC = float(avg([xA, xB]))
            yC = float(avg([yA, yB]))
            zC = float(avg([zA, zB]))

            mp = meshPoint()
            mp.place(xC, yC, zC)
            mp.setShape(cube(size = 0.05, drawWires = False, drawFaces = True, color = (1, 0, 0)))
            mp.shape.move((xC, yC, zC))
            self.shapes.append(mp.shape)
            self.meshPoints.append(mp)
            MPs.append(mp)
            if (pointA.value < self.limit and pointB.value > self.limit) or (pointA.value > self.limit and pointB.value < self.limit):
                mp.setActive(True)
            else:
                mp.setActive(False)

        activeConfig = 0
        sector = meshSector()
        self.meshSectors.append(sector)
        self.shapes.append(sector)

        for i in range(8):
            if points[i].value > self.limit:
                activeConfig += int(2 ** i)
        print('Configuration number: {}'.format(activeConfig))
        if activeConfig > 127:
            activeConfig = 255 - activeConfig
        print('Configuration number: {}'.format(activeConfig))

        config = table[activeConfig]
        print('Configuration: {}'.format(config))
        print('number of points: {}'.format(len(MPs)))
        for data in config:
            a, b, c = data
            locA = MPs[a].location
            locB = MPs[b].location
            locC = MPs[c].location
            sector.addFacet((locA, locB, locC))

        print('stepping')
        self.currentStep += 1
        self.rotateH(0)

    def zoom(self, value):
        self.zoomLevel += value
        self.openGLWidget.update()

    def rotateV(self, value):
        self.rotateDegreeV += value
        self.openGLWidget.update()

    def rotateH(self, value):
        self.rotateDegreeH += value
        self.openGLWidget.update()

    def filter(self, value):
        self.limit = rnd((value / 49.5) -1, -2)
        for d in self.dataPoints:
            if d.value < self.limit:
                d.shape.hide()
            else:
                d.shape.show()
        self.limitDisplay.setText(str(self.limit))
        self.openGLWidget.update()

    def getDataPointByLocation(self, coord):
        x, y, z = coord
        #print(self.dataPoints)
        #print('requested coordinates: {}'.format(coord))
        for dp in self.dataPoints:
            #print('dataPoint.location: {}'.format(dp.location))
            if dp.location == (x, y, z):
                return dp
        return False

    def generate2(self, xIn, yIn, zIn):
        if xIn == 0 and yIn == 0 and zIn == 0:
            return 0.5
        return -0.5

    def generate(self, xIn, yIn, zIn):    #Function which produces semi-random values based on the supplied coordinates.
        i = -int(xIn * yIn * (10 + zIn))
        j = int(xIn * yIn * (10 + zIn))
        if i < j:
            mixer = random.randint(i, j + 1)
        else:
            mixer = random.randint(j, i + 1)
        a = avg([sin(cos(xIn)), tan(tan(yIn)), cos(tan(zIn))])
        out = mixer * a
        while out > 10:
            out -= 5
        while out < -10:
            out += 5
        return float(out / 10)

    #classes------------------------------------------------------------


app = QApplication([])
window = mainWindow()
window.setupUI()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

classes.py:

```py
class cube():
    render = True
    def __init__(self, location = (0, 0, 0), size = 0.1, drawWires = True, drawFaces = False, color = (1, 1, 1)):
        self.location = location
        self.size = size
        self.drawWires = drawWires
        self.drawFaces = drawFaces
        self.color = color
        self.compute()

    def compute(self):
        x, y, z = self.location
        s = self.size / 2
        self.vertices = [    #8 corner points calculated in reference to the supplied center point
                         (-s + x, s + y, -s + z), (s + x, s + y, -s + z),
                         (s + x, -s + y, -s + z), (-s + x, -s + y, -s + z),
                         (-s + x, s + y, s + z), (s + x, s + y, s + z),
                         (s + x, -s + y, s + z), (-s + x, -s + y, s + z)
                        ]
        self.wires = [    #12 tuples referencing the corner points
                      (0,1), (0,3), (0,4), (2,1), (2,3), (2,6),
                      (7,3), (7,4), (7,6), (5,1), (5,4), (5,6)
                     ]
        self.facets = [    #6 tuples referencing the corner points
                       (0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 6, 5), (0, 3, 7, 4),
                       (6, 5, 1, 2), (6, 7, 4, 5), (6, 7, 3, 2)
                      ]
    def show(self):
        self.render = True
    def hide(self):
        self.render = False
    def move(self, location):
        self.location = location
        self.compute()
    def recolor(self, col):
        if type(col) is tuple:
            self.color = col

class dataPoint():
    def __init__(self, location = (0, 0, 0), value = 0, shape = None):
        self.location = location
        self.value = value
        self.shape = shape
    def place(self, x, y, z):
        self.location = (x, y, z)
    def set(self, val):
        self.value = val
    def setShape(self, shape):
        self.shape = shape

class meshPoint():
    active = False
    def __init__(self, location = (0, 0, 0), shape = None):
        self.location = location
        self.shape = shape
        if self.shape != None:
            #print('{} is hiding shape'.format(self))
            self.shape.hide()
    def place(self, x, y, z):
        self.location = (x, y, z)
    def setShape(self, shape):
        self.shape = shape
        if self.shape != None:
            #print('{} is hiding shape'.format(self))
            self.shape.hide()
    def setActive(self, state):
        self.active = state
        if self.active and self.shape != None:
            #print('{} is showing shape'.format(self))
            self.shape.show()
        elif self.shape != None:
            #print('{} is hiding shape'.format(self))
            self.shape.hide()

class meshSector():
    vertices = []
    facets = []
    wires = []
    render = True
    def __init__(self, drawWires = True, drawFaces = False, color = (1, 1, 1)):
        self.drawWires = drawWires
        self.drawFaces = drawFaces
        self.color = color
    def addFacet(self, coords):    #takes a tuple of three location tuples.
        addr = len(self.vertices)
        for c in coords:
            self.vertices.append(c)
        self.facets.append((addr, addr + 1, addr + 2))
        self.wires.append((addr, addr + 1))
        self.wires.append((addr, addr + 2))
        self.wires.append((addr + 1, addr + 2))
```

lookup.py:

```py
table = [    #config number is line number - 2
[],    #config 0
[(0, 1, 2)],
[(0, 3, 9)],
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 9)],
[(3, 4, 5)],
[(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5)],
[(0, 4, 5), (0, 5, 9)],
[(1, 2, 9), (1, 4, 9), (4, 5, 9)],
[(1, 4, 6)],
[(0, 2, 4), (0, 2, 6)],
[(0, 3, 9), (1, 4, 6)],    #config 10
[(2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 9), (2, 4, 6)],
[(1, 3, 5), (1, 5, 6)],
[(0, 2, 6), (0, 3, 6), (3, 5, 6)],
[(0, 1, 5), (0, 5, 9), (1, 5, 6)],
[(2, 5, 6), (2, 5, 9)],
[(2, 7, 10)],
[(0, 1, 7), (0, 7, 10)],
[(2, 7, 10), (0, 3, 9)],
[(1, 3, 9), (1, 7, 10), (1, 9, 10)],
[(2, 6, 10), (3, 4, 5)],    #config 20
[(0, 1, 7), (0, 1, 10), (3, 4, 5)],
[(0, 4, 5), (0, 5, 9), (2, 7, 10)],
[(1, 7, 10), (1, 9, 10), (1, 5, 9), (1, 4, 5)],
[(1, 4, 6), (2, 7, 10)],
[(0, 4, 6), (0, 6, 7), (0, 7, 10)],
[(0, 3, 9), (1, 4, 6), (2, 7, 10)],
[(6, 7, 10), (3, 9, 10), (3, 4, 6)],
[(1, 3, 5), (1, 5, 6), (2, 7, 10)],
[(0, 7, 10), (0, 6, 7), (0, 5, 6), (0, 3, 5)],
[(0, 1, 2), (5, 6, 7), (5, 7, 10), (5, 9, 10)],    #config 30
[(5, 6, 7), (5, 7, 10), (5, 9, 10)],
[(9, 10, 11)],
[(0, 1, 2), (9, 10, 11)],
[(0, 3, 10), (3, 10, 11)],
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 10), (3, 10, 11)],
[(3, 4, 5), (9, 10, 11)],
[(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (9, 10, 11)],
[(0, 4, 5), (0, 5, 11), (0, 10, 11)],
[(2, 10, 11), (4, 5, 11), (1, 2, 4), (2, 4, 11)],
[(1, 4, 6), (9, 10, 11)],    #config 40
[(0, 2, 4), (2, 4, 6), (9, 10, 11)],
[(0, 3, 10), (3, 10, 11), (1, 4, 6)],
[(2, 4, 6), (2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 11), (2, 10, 11)],
[(1, 3, 5), (1, 5, 6), (9, 10, 11)],
[(3, 5, 6), (0, 3, 6), (0, 2, 6), (9, 10, 11)],
[(0, 1, 6), (0, 5, 6), (0, 5, 11), (0, 10, 11)],
[(5, 6, 11), (6, 10, 11), (2, 6, 10)],
[(2, 7, 9), (7, 9, 11)],
[(0, 1, 7), (0, 7, 9), (7, 9, 11)],
[(0, 3, 11), (0, 2, 11), (2, 7, 11)],    #config 50
[(1, 3, 11), (1, 7, 11)],
[(2, 9, 11), (1, 7, 11), (3, 4, 5)],
[(7, 9, 11), (0, 7, 9), (0, 1, 7), (3, 4, 5)],
[(2, 7, 11), (0, 2, 11), (0, 4, 11), (0, 5, 11)],
[(1, 4, 7), (1, 5, 7), (5, 7, 11)],
[(2, 7, 9), (7, 9, 11), (1, 4, 6)],
[(4, 6, 7), (0, 4, 7), (0, 7, 11), (0, 9, 11)],
[(1, 4, 6), (2, 7, 11), (0, 2, 11), (0, 3, 11)],
[(3, 7, 11), (3, 6, 7), (3, 4, 6)],
[(2, 7, 11), (2, 9, 11), (1, 3, 5), (1, 5, 6)],    #config 60
[(0, 9, 11), (0, 7, 11), (0, 6, 7), (0, 3, 6), (3, 5, 6)],
[(2, 7, 11), (0, 2, 11), (0, 5, 11), (0, 1, 5), (1, 5, 6)],
[(5, 6, 7), (5, 7, 11)],
[(5, 8, 11)],
[(0, 1, 2), (5, 8, 11)],
[(0, 3, 9), (5, 8, 11)],
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 9), (5, 8, 11)],
[(3, 4, 8), (3, 8, 11)],
[(3, 4, 8), (3, 8, 11), (0, 1, 2)],
[(0, 9, 11), (0, 8, 11), (0, 4, 8)],    #config 70
[(2, 10, 11), (2, 3, 11), (2, 3, 4), (2, 4, 6)],
[(3, 4, 5), (9, 10, 11)],
[(1, 3, 5), (1, 5, 6), (9, 10, 11)],
[(0, 1, 2), (3, 4 ,5), (9, 10, 11)],
[(2, 3, 9), (2, 3, 4), (2, 4, 6), (5, 8, 11)],
[(3, 1, 6), (3, 6, 8), (3, 8, 11)],
[(7, 9, 10), (5, 7, 9), (1, 5, 7), (1, 4, 5)],
[(6, 7, 10), (3, 9, 10), (3, 4, 6), (3, 6, 10)],
[(6, 8, 11), (6, 9, 11), (2, 6, 9)],
[(2, 7, 10), (5, 8, 11)],    #config 80
[(0, 1, 7), (0, 7, 10), (5, 8, 11)],
[(0, 3, 9), (2, 7, 10), (5, 8, 11)],
[(1, 7, 10), (1, 9, 10), (1, 3, 9), (5, 8, 11)],
[(3, 4, 8), (3, 8, 11), (2, 7, 10)],
[(0, 1, 7), (0, 7, 10), (3, 4, 8), (3, 8, 11)],
[(4, 8, 11), (4, 9, 11), (0, 4, 9), (2, 7, 10)],
[(9, 10, 11), (1, 4, 7), (4, 7, 8)],
[(1, 4, 6), (2, 7, 10), (5, 8, 11)],
[(0, 4, 6), (0, 6, 7), (0, 7, 10), (5, 8, 11)],
[(0, 3, 9), (1, 4, 6), (5, 8, 11), (2, 7, 10)],    #config 90
[(3, 4, 6), (6, 7, 10), (3, 9, 10), (5, 8, 11)],
[(1, 3, 6), (3, 6, 8), (3, 8, 11), (2, 7, 10)],
[(0, 3, 10), (3, 10, 11), (6, 7, 8)],
[(0, 1, 2), (6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11)],
[(6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11)],
[(5, 8, 9), (8, 9, 10)],
[(0, 1, 2), (5, 8, 9), (8, 9, 10)],
[(0, 8, 10), (0, 3, 8), (3, 5, 8)],
[(2, 8, 10), (1, 2, 8), (1, 5, 8), (1, 3, 5)],
[(3, 4, 8), (3, 8, 9), (8, 9, 10)],    #config 100
[(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 8), (3, 8, 9), (8, 9, 10)],
[(0, 4, 8), (0, 8, 10)],
[(1, 4, 8), (1, 2, 8), (2, 8, 10)],
[(1, 4, 6), (5, 8, 9), (8, 9, 10)],
[(0, 4, 6), (0, 2, 6), (5, 8, 9), (8, 9, 10)],
[(1, 4, 6), (0, 8, 10), (0, 3, 5), (1, 4, 6)],
[(3, 4, 5), (2, 6, 8), (2, 8, 10)],
[(1, 6, 8), (1, 3, 8), (3, 8, 10), (3, 9, 10)],
[(0, 3, 9), (2, 6, 8), (2, 8, 10)],
[(0, 1, 10), (1, 6, 10), (6, 8, 10)],    #config 110
[(2, 6, 8), (2, 8, 10)],
[(2, 5, 9), (2, 5, 8), (2, 7, 8)],
[(0, 5, 9), (0, 5, 8), (0, 1, 8), (1, 7, 8)],
[(0, 3, 5), (5, 7, 8), (0, 2, 7), (0, 5, 7)],
[(1, 3, 5), (1, 5, 8), (1, 7, 8)],
[(3, 4, 9), (4, 7, 9), (2, 7, 9), (4, 7, 8)],
[(0, 3, 9), (1, 4, 8), (1, 7, 8)],
[(0, 4, 8), (0, 7, 8), (0, 2, 7)],
[(1, 4, 7), (4, 7, 8)],
[(2, 5, 9), (1, 2, 4), (2, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8)],    #config 120
[(6, 7, 8), (0, 4, 5), (0, 5, 9)],
[(0, 3, 5), (5, 7, 8), (0, 2, 7), (0, 5, 7), (1, 4, 6)],
[(3, 5, 8), (5, 7, 8), (3, 4, 7), (4, 6, 7)],
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 9), (6, 7, 8)],
[(0, 3, 9), (6, 7, 8)],
[(0, 1, 2), (6, 7, 8)],
[(6, 7, 8)]
]
```

run.bat:

```
@echo off
cls
cubes.py
```

This is likely the largest coding project I have ever done.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. For some reason, whenever I instantiated a new meshSector, the values from the last instance carried over. I do not understand why this happens, but my fix was to empty the variables in the `__init__` function.

```py
class meshSector():
    vertices = []
    facets = []
    wires = []
    render = True
    def __init__(self, drawWires = True, drawFaces = False, color = (1, 1, 1)):
        self.drawWires = drawWires
        self.drawFaces = drawFaces
        self.color = color
        #the next four lines prevent data carry-over.
        self.vertices = []
        self.facets = []
        self.wires = []
        self.render = True
    def addFacet(self, coords):    #takes a tuple of three location tuples.
        addr = len(self.vertices)
        for c in coords:
            self.vertices.append(c)
        self.facets.append((addr, addr + 1, addr + 2))
        self.wires.append((addr, addr + 1))
        self.wires.append((addr, addr + 2))
        self.wires.append((addr + 1, addr + 2))
```

As a pleasant side effect, this fix multiplied the performance exponentially, eliminating the lag that I had been seeing. This, I understand. Each meshSector was rendering all the wires in the meshsectors before it. Effectively, 2 sectors was 3, 3 sectors was 6, 4 sectors was 10, etc.